# Search files in buket with wildcard google cloud storage .net

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I have setup cloud storage API in .NET.

> I want to search files in the bucket with matched characters as we do
>   in windows search to find files which contains foo in its name with
>   any extension we type `*foo*.*` it will list all files which contains
>   foo in its name.

can this type of search is supported in google cloud storage with .NET API?

Answer (score 1):

This type of search is not supported by Google Cloud Storage.